# Using FOR loop in CMD to combine .csv files by date created

Tags: csv, cmd

I have a large amount of .csv files that I'm copying into a single .csv file to open in excel. I've been going to the folder with all of the .csv files and using..

```
C:\folder> copy *.csv combined.csv
```

It combines all the files into one csv but sorted alphanumerically. I'd like all of the files to be copied by the date created. I tried to sort by using..

```
C:\folder> dir /od
```

This does show me the files sorted in the way I want but then using the copy command still produces a file sorted alphanumerically. I believe I need to use a For loop and I've tried looking up other answers but I can't get it to work properly. My experience with CMD is very limited. I'm currently at..

```
C:\folder> for %i in ('dir /od *.csv') do copy *.csv combined.csv
```

This just makes multiple combined.csv files sorted the same way as before. I also tried something like..

```
C:\folder> for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('dir /od C:\folder\*.csv') do copy %i >> C:\combined.csv
```

This seemed like it was going to work based on what I saw on the CMD screen but then the file was just full of "The system cannot find the file specified" I took out my folder names to make these more simple but I'm hoping I'm somewhere close. I'm only doing this once in a great while so it's not a script I need to run or anything but just me trying to combine .csv files so I can view them all in order in excel.

Comment: Your file names are not like `30.10.2019  21:59            17.810 file.csv`, but `file.csv` only. Use `dir`'s  `/b` switch for **b**are format (see `dir /?`)

Comment: Also use `type %i >> combined.csv`.  `copy` doesn't print anything to redirect.

Comment: Try this: `> "combined.csv" rem/ & for /F "delims= eol=|" %F in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D /T:C "*.csv"') do if /I not "%F"=="combined.csv" copy "combined.csv" + "%F" "combined.csv" /B` (this relies on the fact that also the last line/row of each file is terminated by a line-break)…

Comment: File names are just file.csv. I've moved all the files from the original PC to my work PC and both the modified date and creation date are still the same as original and still correct as to what I want them to be.

Comment: Thanks aschipfl! That worked.